# How to design supply plumbing for 3-way valve

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, plumbing-fixture

I'm putting in a three-way diverter valve that will supply a rain shower handheld shower or both, similar to this post:

[Building new shower, how can I control the flow of water to two different shower heads?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/75820/building-new-shower-how-can-i-control-the-flow-of-water-to-two-different-shower)

Or similar to this product (referenced in above post):
https://www.signaturehardware.com/three-way-in-wall-shower-diverter-lever-handle.html

Is it as simple as plumbing a 1/2" supply to the three-way diverter? Or is there something else I should do to ensure good water pressure/supply when both are in use?

For example, should I get one that has a 3/4" inlet? Or would it be better to just use two totally separate shower fixtures and plumb them with a plumbing loop?

We have very good water pressure in the house an the house is supplied with 3/4" from the city. We're using PEX. I'm a novice at plumbing and I understand enough to plumb a simple bathroom, but this seems advanced and I don't know anything about what problems could arise. I think the problems I should be concerned about are low pressure and water hammer. This is a new bathroom in an old house so it's a remodel but also completely new construction.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure it's necessary for your fairly simple plan, but could you provide 3/4" lines all the way from the source?